# How to display an image from from Logitech C920 USB webcam with Xamarin.IOS UIImage?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios, webcam

I can't find the format of the webcam, so I don't know if it's JPG, PNG, or what.

I input each frame image from the camera with Windows C# MediaFrameReader.

Then, I send it by socket to my iPad Xamarin.IOS app.

And finally display it: UIImageView = UIImage.LoadFromData( frame )

But no image displays.
I tried loading the UIImageView programmatically from a .jpg file and that works.

Comment: as I suggested the last time you asked this question, you need to save the data from the webcam and figure out what format it is.

Comment: a quick scan of the MediaFrameReader docs turns up "Because the frames will arrive as SoftwareBitmap objects" which would make think it needs to be converted into a format that iOS supports